# where to add the css and js files in the wordpress elementor pages

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, elementor

I created with the elementor page with mine HTML that includes redirect to external css and js files.

*example* :

my elementor page have `"script src='script.js'"` and `"link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'"`

Where to put the `script.js` file and the `style.css` file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a directory like "js" in your theme folder and put the scripts in there. In the code/template the path looks like

```
<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/script.js
```

Comment: but i add the script source in the HTML add option at the Elementor , It still count ?
I mean it is for specific page that created by the elementor

Comment: When you load a script in the footer of your theme (like "Elementor" or something) it will just load.